# Visual Indicators for editable content and non editable content

Tags: user-centered-design, indicator

**Brief Product Description**:
I have been working on a digital project where the product is an online presentation software where the user (Teacher) has presentation slides to select and conducts presentations to the students.

**Problem**:
The user buys slides from the marketplace which will be added to the software library. The user must be able to distinguish between  Guides (collection of slides) bought from the marketplace and their custom-made slides because the slides in the guides can be dragged and dropped when making a custom guide but the content in them cannot be edited and the user must know this. So I was thinking of a kind of indicator that helps users to see that. But don't know if this is the best way. Please help. Thank you

Image 1
[image: Image 1]

Image 2
[image: Image 2]

Comment: What have you come up with so far? I'm not seeing any clear signifier in your screenshot that would indicate whether an element is drag-and-droppable. Also, in your question you mention a library, but I'm not seeing anything labeled as such. Is the 'new guideline' pane the library? In that case, consider using consistent labeling. Your users must not be forced to guess or assume what things are. The "drop slides here" signifier might benefit from higher placement in the visual hierarchy.

Comment: There seems to be some conceptual confusion for me: Are guides divided into those that can be used for a new 'Guideline', and those that can't? What is a guideline vs a Guide?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should work on the information architecture and the flow rather than on a signifier. For example, you could add a section called "your projects". When you click on the template it opens automatically in the section "your projects" without dragging and dropping stuff around.

I would also be careful about how you are using labels. It's not clear the difference between Guides, Slides, and Document. Are these categories of templates you can add to your projects? In this case, be careful to make a hierarchical distinction between "your projects" and the marketplace.

I suggest you give a look at how Canva is handling the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution, but as someone looking at this for the first time, I wouldn't know what the difference is between Guides, Slides, Documents. Maybe rework the terminology